# jQuery AJAX - Not receiving JSON data when on localhost using XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xampp

I'm using this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "http://www.localhost/do_getmemes.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {userid: userid, lastid: lastID},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('bla');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

inside `do_getmemes.php` the post parameters are received successfully and the json is getting generated but I don't get it on `success`?? Console isn't showing anything. It works fine on the website but not when on localhost using XAMPP

It all works inside the php file, this is at the end:

```
file_put_contents('test.json', json_encode($array)); // file generated and not empty
echo json_encode($array);
```

What's the problem here?

**EDIT:**

AJAX usually works, I tested by getting simple string:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.localhost/contact/text.php",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data) // got it
    }
});
```

Comment: have you considered logging something to `error_log()` in your php file to make sure you are getting it? and maybe try calling it directly with [tag:curl] or [tag:postman]

Comment: The error logs aren't showing anything for this php file and I don't know why they would because the json is generated and not empty

Comment: `http://www.localhost/do_getmemes.php`? Was this mangled when transferring the code to the question?

Comment: Are you loading the page from the filesystem, or from the XAMPP web server? AJAX won't work from the filesystem.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP on my pc with windows 10. AJAX does work, I tested it by getting simple text, please check the update of the question in 1 minute

Comment: @El_Vanja what???? ehh no.

Comment: My guess... you are `echo`-ing something else in your file which invalidates JSON parsing. Add an `error` handler to your `$.ajax()` call, eg `error: (_, status, err) => { console.error(status, err) }`. You can also inspect the actual response from your request in your browser's _Network_ dev-tools console

Comment: @Phil nope there aren't any echos/output other than the json. The error code you provided gives: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0, I also added header('Content-Type: application/json'); to the top in the PHP file now but it still doesn't work

Comment: Looks like your PHP script is returning at least some HTML. It won't necessarily be from an `echo`, it could also be something outside the `<?php ... ?>` context. Did you check the actual response in the _Network_ console yet?

Comment: @Phil you are right I deleted everything and added only this: header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$array = array('bla1', 'bla2');
echo json_encode($array); and now it works! But I can't find out what exactly it is because I have go now. Thanks for your help! Please create an answer with this explanation and I will accept it tomorrow and will comment what it was if I find out

Comment: `www.localhost` should just be `localhost`

Comment: @Barmar whatever OP has seems to work fine for them

Comment: @Phil alright I got it. XAMPP has turned on all kind of "error" messages by default even if it's something irrelevant. This is the solution for the PHP file: error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0); post it and I'll accept :D

Comment: @Barmar true it's without www. the domain is in a variable so I didn't see if it's with or without

Comment: Or you could, you know, fix the actual error

Comment: Yeah I'll do but just to make sure the API won't stop working and make the visitors leave this is a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were irrelevant warnings which were also sent through the API back and causing `parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error.

Besides fixing them this is the way to ensure the APIs wills till work:

Disable the warnings inside the PHP file:

```
error_reporting(0); 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```